# float right issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

i want to let a div float right with a fixed size and the rest of the space needs to be left.
I have done this the flowing way:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="rightCntr">
</div>
<div id="leftCntr">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#leftCntr { 
float: none; /* not needed, just for clarification */
background: #e8f6fe;
/* the next props are meant to keep this block independent from the other floated one */
width: auto;
overflow: hidden; 
}

#rightCntr { float: right; width: 213px;}
```

this works great in Firefox and Chrome but in IE8 it goes all wrong. [Example](http://www.goedkopevakantie.com/bestemming/griekenland?url=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nb2Vka29wZXZha2FudGllLmNvbS9yZWlzYnVyZWF1L3pvbi5zdW53ZWIubmwvdmFrYW50aWVfZ3JpZWtlbmxhbmQvem9la2VuLmFzcHg/TnM9cElzQ2hhcnRlciU3YzAlN2MlN2NwUHJpY2U=)

Comment: Do you know how wide the left container needs to be (in pixels), or is it variable?

Comment: Try to `clear:both` after `float:rignt`.

Comment: Can you share your `<head>` section, Document mode is `IE5 quirks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example jsBin: http://jsbin.com/ixebuf/1/ (tested on IE8, Fx)
(backgrounds are placed for testing purpose)

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rightCntr {
  float: right;
  width: 213px;
  background: gray;
}
#leftCntr {
   margin-right: 213px; 
   background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve proper results in IE, you can use this instead of float:right.

```
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    text-align: right;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#leftCntr { 
    float: left; 

    /* not needed, just for clarification */ 
    background: #e8f6fe; 

    /* the next props are meant to keep this block independent 
     *  from the other floated one    
     */ 
    width: 100px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 100px; 
} 

#rightCntr { 
    float: right; 
    width: 213px; 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    background: red; 
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Try this.remove background colors